# Issue with \xrightarrow

Tags: xetex, arrows, unicode-math

I get something weird from the \xrightarrow command: the line is dashed.
[image]

Here is my `main.tex`file:

```
\documentclass[twoside,titlepage,paper=a4,fontsize=12pt,numbers=noenddot,cleardoublepage=empty,openright]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}

\usepackage{feynmp}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{slashed}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{eps}{*}{}

\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=eqs,placement={tbp},name=Éq.]{eq}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\parbox{30mm}{
\vspace{4.3mm}
\begin{fmffile}{self}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(100,75)
    \fmfcmd{
    vardef middir(expr p,ang) =
     dir(angle direction length(p)/2 of p + ang)
    enddef;
    style_def arrow_right expr p =
     shrink(.7);
      cfill(arrow p
       shifted (8thick*middir(p,-90)));
     endshrink
    enddef;}
    \fmfset{curly_len}{2mm}
    \fmfleft{i} \fmfright{o}
    \fmf{quark,label=$p$}{i,v1} \fmf{quark,label=$p$}{v2,o}
    \fmf{quark,tension=.3,label=$p+l$}{v1,v2}
    \fmf{arrow_right,tension=.3}{v2,v1}
    \fmf{gluon,left,tension=.1,label=$l$}{v1,v2}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
} 
\qquad \xrightarrow[\: \varepsilon \to 0 \:]{}
\quad i \, \slashed{p} \, C_F\, \frac{g_C^2}{4\pi} \, \frac{1}{\varepsilon} + \dots
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

To compile, I run:

```
latexmk -quiet -e '$pdflatex=q/xelatex %O %S/' -f -pdf -synctex=1 -jobname=Document -outdir=$PWD/Result $PWD/main.tex
cd Result/
mpost self.mp
cd ..
latexmk -quiet -e '$pdflatex=q/xelatex %O %S/' -f -pdf -synctex=1 -jobname=Document -outdir=$PWD/Result $PWD/main.tex
```

Would you know how I could fix that ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

(EDIT:)

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage{unicode-math}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
 \xrightarrow[\: \varepsilon \to 0 \:]{}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: this appears to be a bug in `unicode-math`.  (there are some problems with the `\xrightarrow` being tested in the new beta version of the `stix` fonts, so this isn't surprising.  i will ping will robertson.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton — actually I don't really see why `unicode-math` needs to reimplement `amsmath` whenever something doesn't work; it would preferable to fix `amsmath` instead :) Presumably the problem would go away if U+23AF (horizontal line extender) were being used directly without the need to "back up" as in @egreg's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the backing up done by `\arrowfill@` is insufficient when Latin Modern Math is used. Here's a fix:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\ifxetex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \makeatletter
  \patchcmd{\arrowfill@}{-7mu}{-14mu}{}{}
  \patchcmd{\arrowfill@}{-7mu}{-14mu}{}{}
  \patchcmd{\arrowfill@}{-2mu}{-4mu}{}{}
  \patchcmd{\arrowfill@}{-2mu}{-4mu}{}{}
  \makeatother
\fi

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
 \xrightarrow[\mspace{28mu}]{}\\
 \xrightarrow[\mspace{30mu}]{}\\
 \xrightarrow[\mspace{32mu}]{}\\
 \xrightarrow[\mspace{34mu}]{}\\
 \xrightarrow[\mspace{36mu}]{}\\
 \xrightarrow[\mspace{38mu}]{}\\
 \xrightarrow[\mspace{40mu}]{}\\
 \xrightarrow[\mspace{42mu}]{}\\
 \xrightarrow[\mspace{44mu}]{}\\
 \xrightarrow[\mspace{46mu}]{}\\
 \xrightarrow[\mspace{48mu}]{}\\
 \xrightarrow[\mspace{50mu}]{}\\
 \xrightarrow[\mspace{52mu}]{}\\
 \xrightarrow[\mspace{54mu}]{}\\
 \xrightarrow[\mspace{56mu}]{}\\
 \xrightarrow[\mspace{58mu}]{}\\
 \xrightarrow[\mspace{60mu}]{}\\
 \xrightarrow[\mspace{62mu}]{}\\
 \xrightarrow[\mspace{64mu}]{}\\
 \xrightarrow[\mspace{66mu}]{}\\
 \xrightarrow[\mspace{68mu}]{}\\
 \xrightarrow[\mspace{70mu}]{}\\
 \xrightarrow[\mspace{72mu}]{}\\
 \xrightarrow[\mspace{74mu}]{}\\
 \xrightarrow[\mspace{76mu}]{}\\
 \xrightarrow[\mspace{78mu}]{}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's the output if the four `\patchcmd` lines are commented out.

[image]

One can observe that the first and the last parts have gaps, while the middle parts are not overlapping each other. The default backing up is -7mu for the terminal parts and -2mu for the middle parts.

Answer (score 0):

It's got something to do with how `\:` is interpreted.  The following code doesn't have the same problem.

```
\documentclass{article}


\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
 \xrightarrow[\; \varepsilon \to 0 \;]{}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I get exactly the same, a dashed arrow.

Comment: Same here. This doesn't answer the question; the problem remains. It is a bug in `unicode-math`. I'd suggest you either to modify the answer or to delete it.

Comment: With `\;` I get a regular arrow.  Yes, it is a bug in unicode-math.

Comment: Perhaps the whole question should be turned into a bug report to the unicode-math packag authors.

Comment: @JPi Will did just that: https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/314